# Variable "produit" does not exist

Tags: symfony, twig

I am a beginner on Symfony. I'm stuck because I can't debug my e-commerce application. I really don't see what the problem is. I'm trying to display the data in my database but it gives me an error message no matter what I try.

When I perform a dump and die, it outputs the fields from the product table but not the data.
When I remove the dump and die, and I put this url /product/Rossi (a name contained in the database) it gives me an error message: "App\Entity\Produit" object not found by "Symfony\ Bridge\Doctrine\ArgumentResolver\EntityValueResolver".
When I try to put /details in place of /{name}, and put this url /product/details in the search bar, I get this error message:
Variable "product" does not exist.

Thank you for your help !!

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Produit;


#[Route('/produit', name: 'produit_')]
class ProduitController extends AbstractController
{
    
#[Route('/', name: 'index')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('produit/index.html.twig'
        );
    }
    #[Route('/{nom}', name: 'details')]
    public function details(Produit $produit): Response
    {
        
        // dd($produit->getNom());
        return $this->render('produit/details.html.twig'
    );

    }
}
```

Entity

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Entity;
    
    
    use App\Repository\ProduitRepository;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    
    #[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProduitRepository::class)]
    class Produit
    {
        
        #[ORM\Id]
        #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
        #[ORM\Column]
        private ?int $id = null;
    
        #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
        private ?string $nom = null;
    
        #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
        private ?string $description = null;
    
        #[ORM\Column]
        private ?int $prix = null;
    
        #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'produits')]
        private ?Categorie $id_categorie = null;
    
        #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'produits', targetEntity: Images::class)]
        private Collection $images;
    
        #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'produit', targetEntity: CommandeDetails::class)]
        private Collection $commandeDetails;
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->commandeDetails = new ArrayCollection();
        }
    
    
        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    
        public function getNom(): ?string
        {
            return $this->nom;
        }
    
        public function setNom(string $nom): static
        {
            $this->nom = $nom;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getDescription(): ?string
        {
            return $this->description;
        }
    
        public function setDescription(string $description): static
        {
            $this->description = $description;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getPrix(): ?int
        {
            return $this->prix;
        }
    
        public function setPrix(int $prix): static
        {
            $this->prix = $prix;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getIdCategorie(): ?Categorie
        {
            return $this->id_categorie;
        }
    
        public function setIdCategorie(?Categorie $id_categorie): static
        {
            $this->id_categorie = $id_categorie;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return Collection<int, Images>
         */
        public function getImages(): Collection
        {
            return $this->images;
        }
    
        public function addImage(Images $image): static
        {
            if (!$this->images->contains($image)) {
                $this->images->add($image);
                $image->setProduits($this);
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function removeImage(Images $image): static
        {
            if ($this->images->removeElement($image)) {
                // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
                if ($image->getProduits() === $this) {
                    $image->setProduits(null);
                }
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return Collection<int, CommandeDetails>
         */
        public function getCommandeDetails(): Collection
        {
            return $this->commandeDetails;
        }
    
        public function addCommandeDetail(CommandeDetails $commandeDetail): static
        {
            if (!$this->commandeDetails->contains($commandeDetail)) {
                $this->commandeDetails->add($commandeDetail);
                $commandeDetail->setProduit($this);
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function removeCommandeDetail(CommandeDetails $commandeDetail): static
        {
            if ($this->commandeDetails->removeElement($commandeDetail)) {
                // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
                if ($commandeDetail->getProduit() === $this) {
                    $commandeDetail->setProduit(null);
                }
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        
    }
```

twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Détails des produits{% endblock %}

{% block body %}


<h1>Details {{ produit.nom }} </h1>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Add the product to your view like this : `return $this->render('produit/details.html.twig',['product' => $product ]  ); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for the 'Variable 'Product' doesn't exist' message

You need to pass your Object to your view.

You can do it this way:

```
#[Route('/{nom}', name: 'details')]
public function details(Produit $produit): Response
{
    return $this->render('produit/details.html.twig', [
        'produit' => $produit
    ]);
}
```

Now concerning your urls:

'details' is just the name of your route. You will never put it in the url.

The correct way to call your details route is to put this in your url:

**/produit/{name-of-a-product}** for you in instance **/produit/Rossi**

If it tells you the product doesn't exist. Please verify that you have a product with the name 'Rossi' in your DB.